# C# Read EventLog

Tags: c#

How to read logs from the event log:

> Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational

When I use EventLog.GetEventLogs () I only get logs:

- ACEEventLog
- Application
- HardwareEvents
- Internet Explorer
- Key
- Management Service
- ODiag OSession
- Security
- System
- Windows
- PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I used EventLogQuery and EventLogSession.

However, I have a problem how to use the code below but for the admin of the local remote computer. Typing ".", "" Or "computer name" as domain doesn't help. The omission results in a syntax error.

```
EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession( 
"ComputerName",            // Remote Computer 
"Domain",            //Domain 
"Admin",               // Username 
pw,
SessionAuthentication.Default);
```